# Programmatically Detecting Browser Cookies Enable/Disabled without Redirect or Javascript?

Tags: browser, cookies

How is http://supportdetails.com detecting if cookies are enabled or disabled without a server side redirect?

Using Firefox and the Developer plug I've disabled Javascript and toggled Cookies on and off. It correctly detects without, as far as I can tell, a server side redirect. How are they doing this?

Comment: It gives the wrong answer for me - with cookies enabled and script disabled (using NoScript), it says that cookies are disabled.

Comment: The OPs website may not do it correctly, but Amazon does it without redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try the following code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = "Are cookies enabled?: " + navigator.cookieEnabled;
    return x;
}
</script>
```